# Golang identify and validate json value set to null or not provided

Tags: json, go, validation

I have API which accepts PATCH method and updates given fields.
PATCH request with below body changes age of User.

```json
{
   "age": 10
}
```

I had problem on treating `null` value.
My `User` struct as below:

```golang
type User struct {
    Name string
    Age int
    Schedule *schedule
}

type Schedule struct {
    time int
    weekdays []int
}
```

To remove schedule field on user, request body should be like:

```json
{
    "schedule": null
}
```

Then, I have to identify whether null value is given or not provided anything, which is not possible with above definition.
I wrote new struct that helps identifying it (https://www.calhoun.io/how-to-determine-if-a-json-key-has-been-set-to-null-or-not-provided/):

```golang
type User struct {
    Name 
    Age int
    Schedule Optional[Schedule]
}

type Optional[T any] struct {
    Value   *T
    Defined bool
}

func (t *Optional[T]) UnmarshalJSON(data []byte) error {
    t.Defined = true
    return json.Unmarshal(data, &t.Value)
}

func (t *Optional[T]) IsNullDefined() bool {
    return t.Defined && t.Value == nil
}

func (t *Optional[T]) HasValue() bool {
    return t.Defined && t.Value != nil
}
```

And, now I have problem that actions are different between

```json
{
    "age": null
}
```

which will be ignored and

```json
{
    "schedule": null
}
```

which will remove the schedule.

How can I handle and prevent `null` value for other type, which should be type error?

---

Edit:

In one sentence, I want to reject all `null` value given field (not a non-provided) except Optional struct. You can suggest me any other solution that solves the problem.

Comment: Define a type analogous to your `Optional[T]`, and have the new type compare the `data` passed to `UnmarshalJSON` against `null`, i.e. `if string(data) == "null" {`, and if `true`, then you can have `UnmarshalJSON` return an error. You could call the new type `Required[T]`, for example.

Comment: @mkopriva Thanks for new idea. With your solution, I have to put `Required` to all fields except `Optional` fields. I think `"age": null` should be rejected since `age` is integer type and not nullable. Is it be possible?

Comment: No it's not possible, not with the standard library's `encoding/json`. See [`json.Unmarshal`](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/json@go1.21.0#Unmarshal): *"The JSON null value unmarshals into an interface, map, pointer, or slice by setting that Go value to nil. __Because null is often used in JSON to mean “not present,” unmarshaling a JSON null into any other Go type has no effect on the value and produces no error__."*

Comment: @mkopriva Then should I change my API spec to achieve removing the schedule?

Comment: Your API (JSON) should not depend on schedule missing from the object vs schedule being null.

Comment: A value of null and not there at all have the same semantics to almost all people in the API business. The downvotes probably stem from your idea of distinguishing these two. For patching JSON (which is a complicated problem) there is a proposed standard JSON Patch (with libraries for Go too) and you are trying to reimplement that (badly).

Comment: @Volker I follow Merge Patch JSON (rfc7396). And, Merge Patch treats `null` as removal of field. Am I wrong? Anyway, I didn't know that there're go libraries for JSON PATCH. I found it and try to read.

Comment: I found a good library thanks to you. https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/evanphx/json-patch/v5#MergePatch

Comment: Not exactly an answer to the question but i would advice to try using https://jsonpatch.com/ instead . Or you could use DELETE method to the `path/to/resource/schedule` to unset

Comment: I was thinking about RFC 6902.

Comment: Perhaps your implementation of `Optional` isn't quite as complete as it could be?  Try... https://go.dev/play/p/dBKQRazC7_f

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Try making the `Age` a `*int` type.</strike>

Try making the `Age` an `Optional[int]` type. https://go.dev/play/p/f56pdESOEt7

Comment: It does not solve the problem. `*int` also ignores `"age": null`. i.e., Cannot identify `age` field is given.

Comment: Thanks. It solves the problem, but I want the general solution that type validation in terms of language. With the solution and if I want to reject `null`, I have to put all my field `Optional` and code that checks valid. I think it's not a good idea.

Comment: @osflw what exactly do you need to do? You need to identify all the following 3 cases, right?

1. Valid `age`
2. null `age`
3. `age` not supplied.

With pointers, you'll get only 2 out of 3 options. It is not possible without the custom struct

Comment: Yeah, but by default, it rejects all `null` value given. So that only `Optional` field can accept `null` and remove the field.

Comment: What do you mean by "ignored" and "rejected". Even with the pointers, you'll always be able to distinguish between a `nil`/`null` or a valid value. Can you share a go.dev link explaining expected and actual output?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255045/discussion-between-saurabh-prakash-and-osflw).

Answer (score -1):

Found a solution from @Volker and post self answer:

The above question uses Merge Patch JSON (rfc7396). There's a library for it.

https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/evanphx/json-patch/v5#MergePatch

I pull GET result and merge GET result and json patch body. Then, you can notice which values are nullified.